# How much mobile data is needed during the first install?

Tags: system-installation, internet

During the first install of Ubuntu from the latest version ISO. Let's assume worst case scenario. Let's assume I enable the installer to update and download all drivers including proprietary. I click yes on any and all suggested packages or software the installer prompts.

Let's assume that when I install Ubuntu, I want everything to work from the word go. I want to get anything needed and enjoy a full first install.

How much mobile data must I plan for during this install?
Keep in mind. This is not a question relying on variables. This is a worst case scenario question.

Comment: This question is merely to prevent the message "NO internet connection" during install.

Comment: i think it depends on the ISO file that you downloaded already.. i several times installed Ubuntu 18.04 dated May 1st. till today.. i guess there are point releases after May 1st which covers updates.. so the ISO size on may 1st will get all updates till today. best way is to download the latest iso as on today and install.

Comment: Since this depends on how many packages have been updated since the ISO was released, there's no definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's assume that when I install linux ubuntu, I want everything to work from the word go. I want to get anything needed and enjoy a full first install.

What's everything?

There's a lot of packages that doesn't make sense, unless you're in a very specific field, for instance special libraries or packages for e.g. python for a special purpose.

There's mutually exclusive packages, and there's alternatives that doesn't make sense to install at the same time in many cases.

A desktop system doesn't typically need apache2, postfix, and so forth, but if you are a web developer, it may make sense to install them. And so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I did it install Ubuntu in the same way you described. 
It took 382Mb of data to update itself after installation. But it is still depends because new updates can have different sizes.

Comment: Bless you I honestly very much appreciate your answer.

Comment: @RenierFourie most of that data was taken by Firefox and Kernel. But you don't need update Firefox to make it operational.